# AWS RDS + INTO OUTFILE

Tags: mysql, csv, amazon-web-services, dump, rds

I understand that we can't do a INTO OUTFILE when we are dealing with RDS.

From my research, I have tried the following,

```
mysql -uusername -ppassword -hhost -default-character-set=utf8 dbname < select.sql | sed -e 's/\t/,/g' > test.csv

mysql -uusername -ppassword -hhost -default-character-set=utf8 dbname < select.sql | perl -F"\t" -lane 'print join ",", map {s/"/""/g; /^http://\d.+$/ ? $_ : qq("$_")} @F ' > test.csv
```

For some reason, if I limit the select query in the select.sql to a certain number, it gave me the correct result with all Arabic wordings intact, but once I increase the limit by 1, the encoding becomes messed up and all Arabic wordings turned to rubbish characters.

I have checked that the CentOS server that I'm running on has the locale set to UTF8 and I have also checked that the data seems to be normal without any issue.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: As ever, the key to debugging is to break the problem down. Run the SQL and output it to a file without the `sed` or `perl` pipeilines. Do it for your successful N rows, and then your unsucessful N+1 rows, and `diff` the two files. Are they actually completely different, or is it the last line that's corrupted? Look at them in a hex editor and see if you can spot what the "rubbish characters" actually are. Look carefully at the values in that extra row; is the text already messed up in the database? Somewhere along this process you may find an example we can examine here, rather than guessing.

Comment: Hi @IMSoP, I have done what you suggested earlier and the diff result was actually printing a lot of rubbish character and the difference was not just the extra N+1 line so I'm currently wondering whether this is something to do with the data but couldn't really see what the issue from inspecting the data on some mysql application.

Comment: I have managed to resolve the issue, by using hex editor I was able to see the difference and then see the difference. Thanks!

Comment: That's good news! If you think the solution might help someone else out in future, please consider [answering your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that this post doesn't show up as unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there was a column that hosted some contents with BLOB data type which caused the encoding to be messed up when it's being dumped into the csv (might be due to the length of the data and mixed characters), dropping the field as it wasn't used eventually resolved the issue.